# "Windows Disc Image Burner" missing from both windows 10 and windows 11

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, compact-disc

[image]I can't find Windows Disc Image Burner on either of my Window 10 machines or Windows 11 machine.  Do I need to pick something in add/remove windows features or something?

It's not just missing from the context menu.  It doesn't show up if I try to look for it in apps and features either.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This option has disappeared from the context-menu for ISO files, although
the burner program is still there in Windows.

A workaround that doesn't involve any registry hacks is:

- Right-click on the file and select "Open With"
- Select "Choose another app"
- Select "More apps"
- Scroll to the bottom and select "Look for another app on this PC"
- Browse to folder `C:\Windows\System32` and select `isoburn.exe`
- Click Open.

Now you can go ahead and burn your ISO.

Comment: Great, Microsoft made it easier to use.....